# Change web page title automatically using cloudscribe.Web.Navigation current node

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cloudscribe

My project is using asp.net core and `cloudscribe.Web.Navigation` for main navigation and breadcrumbs. Everything is good now. One step further I want to implement is to change title automatically using current node information.

Is there any solution to archive this?

Comment: no there isn't. cloudscribe.Web.Navigation is a menu component nothing more. If you are using cloudscribe SimpleContent for pages you can change the page title and the menu node will automatically update to the new page title but the menu node cannot edit a page.

Comment: Thanks for you help. But is there any way to inject NavigationViewModel into controller?